# How can I get selected values from Bootstrap multiple selectpicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-selectpicker

Here is my `select` element and it has `multiple` attribute;

```
<select id="dd-personnels" onchange="personnelChange()" asp-items="Model.Personnels" multiple data-max-options="1" class="form-control form-control-sm selectpicker"></select>
```

Here is my code to initialize a `selectpicker` from `select` above;

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({ liveSearch: true });
```

How can I get selected values in the `onchange` of the select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if inline event handler is a bad practice you need to add two keywords to your inline:

```
<select id="dd-personnels" onchange="personnelChange(this, event)" ....
```

Now your function is:

```
function personnelChange(ele, event) {
   var val = $(ele).selectpicker('val');
   console.log(val);
}
```

For details you can take a look to the [documentation](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/)

The snippet:

```js
function personnelChange(ele, event) {
    var val = $(ele).selectpicker('val');
    console.log(val);
}

 $('#dd-personnels').selectpicker({
    liveSearch: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>0
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select id="dd-personnels" onchange="personnelChange(this, event)" asp-items="Model.Personnels" multiple data-max-options="1" class="form-control form-control-sm selectpicker">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Barbecue</option>
</select>
```

Comment: In the code-behind if you bind an int array; when post the form, selected values comes in bounded array. I discovered this a couple of minutes ago :))